# Function $\mu$ such that is outer measure but not measure.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $\mu :\mathcal{P}(\left\{0,1 \right\} ) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$  $$\mu(A) =  \begin{cases} 0 \quad A = \emptyset \\ 1 \quad \emptyset \not= A \in \mathcal{P}(\left\{0,1 \right\} ) \end{cases} $$

Is it true that $\mu$ is outer measure, but is not measure?

In my opinion it is true. Firstly we have that for $$A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$$  is  $$\mu(A) \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$$.

Because:

- if $A = \emptyset$ then for all $n$ we have $A_n = \emptyset$ so inequality is true
- if $A \not= \emptyset$ then exsists $k$ such that $A_k \not= \emptyset$ so inequality is obviously.

But $\mu$ is not measure because for disjoints $A_n$ condition $$\mu \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$$ is not satisfied:

For $$A_1 = \left\{0 \right\} \\ A_2 = \left\{1 \right\} \\ A_3 = A_4 = ... = \emptyset   $$

we have:

$$\mu \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \right) = 1 \not= 2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$$

Could you check it and tell me, Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed $\mu$ in this case is only an outer measure.

Some remarks, if you want to show that $\mu$ is not a measure it is sufficient to take $A_1 = \{0\}$ and $A_2 = \{1\}$, then
$\mu(A_1 \cup A_2) = 1 \neq 2 = \mu(A_1) + \mu(A_2)$.
A measure is a countably additive function so in particular it is additive.

To show that $\mu \colon 2^{X} \rightarrow [0, \infty]$, where $X:=\{0,1\}$ is an outer measure you have to verify 3 conditions

1) $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$

**Answer** Satisfied trivially.

2) For any two subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$,
$$ A\subseteq B\quad\text{implies}\quad\mu(A) \leq \mu(B).$$

**Answer**
Let $A$, $B$ be subsets of $X$, such that $A \subset B$,
we can see that $\mu(B) =1$ or $\mu(B)=0$, if $\mu(B)=0$ then $A=\varnothing$ and $\mu(B)=\mu(A)=0$ so the condition is satisfied if $\mu(B) =1$ then $\mu(A) = 1$ or $\mu(A)=0$,
so in all the cases $\mu(A) \leq \mu(B)$.

3) For any sequence $\{A_j\}$ of subsets of $X$ (pairwise disjoint or not),
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\right) \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu(A_j).$$

**Answer**
LHS equals $0$ or $1$, RHS is always greater or equal, easy observation.

You seemed to combine conditions 2) and 3), but since this exercise is easy I wouldn't do that.